# Regexp Replace '' - Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

Gurus!!
I have been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out how to replace a `''` with some character
e.g

```
select regexp_replace('','','XX');
```

Can anyone help me !!

Comment: Your expression tries to replace empty strings within an empty string with XX - which makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think something went wrong with your formatting. It looks like you're trying to replace a blank string with something. If you're unable to write exactly what you want to replace, just provide the character's name or description.

Comment: maybe `case when my_field = '' then 'XX' else my_field end`?

Comment: Sorry I should have asked the full question .. so here is a regex which takes out the digit just infront of **"?haid"** . Now there are cases where there are no digits and so the regex returns a ''. This is causing the cast to integer to fail. I am trying to fix this.                                                            
    `Select regexp_substr(regexp_substr('https:-2027-11217432?
    haid=4052118&uperty1','-[[:digit:]]+\\?haid'),'[[:digit:]]+')::int

    Select regexp_substr(regexp_substr('https:-2027-?
    haid=4052118&uperty1','-[[:digit:]]+\\?haid'),'[[:digit:]]+')::int`

Comment: Please Edit your question showing some sample input values and also the result you would like out of your regex expression. Please keep it as simple as possible, to just show the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 single quotes to escape each single quote to be replaced.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test AS SELECT 'aaa''''bbb' as value
; 
SELECT * FROM test
;
/*  value
------------
 aaa''bbb
*/
SELECT REPLACE(value,'''''','XX') FROM test
;
/* replace
------------
 aaaXXbbb
*/
```